# Romanian Embassy in London

Tags: visas, romania

From the [website](http://mae.ro/en/node/2058) I've been told to submitted my application to the diplomatic missions and consular posts.

I live in London, here are my questions:

1. "M.E.I.C. House, 344 Kensington High Street, London W14 8NS" is this the address I should come to submit my application?
2. What are the opening timings?

Called the embassy but told me to send an email. No response yet.

Comment: in london, "W14 8NS" is a **postcode**. "Kensington High Street" is the name of a street (like "Smith Street").  344 is the number, on Kensington High Street.  Note that "M.E.I.C. House" is just the name of a building -- like say "Empire State Building".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers to both questions are found on the website of the Romanian embassy in the UK under the [section "consular services, visas"](http://london.mae.ro/en/node/818)

In short they are:
1 - yes that's correct.
2:

> You may apply for or collect the Romanian Visa, in person, based on
>   prior appointment, TUESDAY from 14.00 to 15.00 hrs or FRIDAY from
>   10.00 to 11.00 hrs (excluding public holidays).

And the page hints:

> You may find additional information on Romanian visa and make an
>   appointment at http://evisa.mae.ro/.